# getVar() from selected option input codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter-4

I have view

```
<!-- input-text -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <?php $name = 'name';
        $placeholder = 'Nama Lengkap';
        $value = old($name); ?>
        <label for="<?= $name; ?>"><?= $placeholder; ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control <?= ($validation->hasError($name)) ? "is-invalid" : ''; ?>" id="<?= $name; ?>" name="<?= $name; ?>" placeholder="<?= $placeholder; ?>" value="<?= $value ?>">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          <?= $validation->getError($name); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
<!-- input-select -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <?php $name = 'gender';
        $placeholder = 'Jenis Kelamin';
        $value = old($name); ?>
        <label for="<?= $name; ?>"><?= $placeholder; ?></label>
        <select name="<?= $name; ?>" class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" id="<?= $name; ?>">
          <option value="0">Laki-laki</option>
          <option value="1">Perempuan</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

and controller

```
public function create(){
dd($this->request->getVar());}
```

it show only name, but gender doesn't. How to show the value of selected option in CodeIgniter 4?

Comment: Well I took your code and put some wrapper code around it (which is all the code you didn't provide) so this could be tested and there is no problem at all.  To say you can see 'name' and not 'gender' is a little "unusual". I get name, gender and the missing submit using dd() and var_dump().

Answer (score 0):

when you try to catch your post in controller u should type the name variable of the input

```
   public function create(){
       dd($this->request->getVar('gender'));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use form helper, try it:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Nama Lengkap</label>
  <?php echo form_input('name', set_value('name'), 'class="form-control" placeholder="Nama Lengkap"'); ?>
  <?php if(!empty($errors)){ ?>
    <em class="text-danger"><?php echo $errors->getError('name') ?></em>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="gender">Jenis Kelamin</label>
  <?php echo form_dropdown('gender', ['0' => 'Laki-laki', '1' => 'Perempuan'], [], 'class="form-control"'); ?>
</div>
```

Hope it helpful, cheers...